# url() in Symfony2 returning incorrectly in prod env

Tags: url, symfony, development-environment, production

My project was at `http://localhost/project/web/`, this worked fine. But I thought it better to develop of something like `http://project.dev` - this works fine in the dev env but when in prod the following twig code

```
{{ path('homepage') }}
```

Outputs `/project/` which is wrong as it just needs to output `/` now. Is there a setting I am missing somewhere?

I have cleared my prod cache too.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Apache conf looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName project.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/web"
</VirtualHost>
```

and .htaccess is;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2**

The homepage route looks like this

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: Don't you have any remaining alias or url rewrite in your Apache config ?

Comment: It looks OK... I guess you've reloaded Apache after changing its config. Are you sure no other vHost is catching your request ?

Comment: What's your routing config for `homepage`?